# BLE power efficiency and reducing of antenna transmission each 1 minutes

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, consumption

I have a BLE beacon that have some sensors embedded. This beacon should read every minutes all the sensors value and update the characteristics. These characteristics have theirs notifications enabled.

In the other side my phone should read these characteristics, analyze them and notify the user if something wrong.

The beacon has his own embedded RTC (real time clock) that trigger an interruption to inform the beacon that minute has passed and he should start reading sensors data and update characteristics values.

This beacon work on battery and I'm worried a lot about the power efficiency. The most things that i'm worried about is the antenna transmission and reception which consume a lot of power compared to the rest of the system.

So I'm looking for a method to save power. My idea is to limit the antenna transmission and let the antenna in inactive mode and only active it once per minute when the beacon should read the sensors value and update the characteristic value.
Is that possible to do that without loosing connection between the beacon and my phone. And how the phone know exactly when he should listen to the updated characteristic values.

For example if the beacon and the phone are working fine and exchanging data every minutes , in case I move away with my phone for example for 30 minutes and I come back did the connection reestablish automatically ??

in the actual situation when I move away from the beacon from my phone for 5 seconds or more I lose connection in both side.

Is there any communication method that save my beacon power consumption ?

My BLE beacon chip is the nrf51822.

All your suggestions/idea are welcomed.

Comment: Then debug. And if it doesn't work, come back with a proper question.

Comment: Your terminology is confusing because a beacon doesn't make a connection (i.e. isn't paired with anything), it only sends an advertisement.

Answer (score 0):

Consider not creating a connection and instead make nrf51822 send the sensor data in ADVERTISE packets once every minute.